# HttpSessionEventPublisher not working in java config

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a mature java web application that uses spring security (4.2.3, java8, tomcat8), and includes a view that allows a user to query the session registry to see who else is logged in. This depends on HttpSessionEventPublisher to notify the session registry when a user logs out.
The original implementation used web.xml config, but I have mostly reimplemented that using java config now. The last thing I refactored was the HttpSessionEventPublisher.
When I moved it from a web.xml declaration into my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter it stopped working. Specifically, logged-out sessions are no longer being removed from the registry.
I know the bean is being instantiated (the factory method is being called).

This is the java config suggested in the reference docs:

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

Is there some trick needed to get this to work in java config?

Answer (score 4):

`HttpSessionEventPublisher` should be registered as a standard listener not as spring bean. check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionEventPublisher.html).

So, I think you need to register it using `WebApplicationInitializer` as follows:

```
public final class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  @Override
  public void onStartup(final ServletContext ctx) {
    ctx.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
  }
}
```